# Possibility to declare variable from function in IF statement?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, return

I'm back again. I had this little question about a possibility that I could declare a variable in the IF condition from a function, and to use it inside the statement itself.

Ok so, I'm curious to see if there's a way to declare a variable inside an IF statement's condition, and use that further along the statement as follows:

```js
function SomeFunc() {return true}
if (let n = SomeFunc()) {
    console.log(n); // true
    // n is truthy
} else {
    // Would never run, because it always returns true.
    // This is just an example though, where it can return a truthy or falsy value dependent on the input context I could give it.
    console.log(n); // false (if it actually returned 'false')
    // n is falsy
}
```

Is there any way to do this, without having to run the function twice and not have it run outside the IF statement?

(Not like this though):

```js
let n = SomeFunc();
if (n) { ... } else { ... }

// Or this:
if (SomeFunc()) {
    let n = SomeFunc();
} else { ... }
```

I'd like to have one function being declared inside the condition, to minimalise line usage and have it - for me - clean. I hope there's a way to declare a variable inside of an IF condition.

Thank you in advance.
~Q

Answer (score 2):

The syntax does not allow `let`, `const` or `var` to appear at that position.
But you could just define the variable (without initialisation) and then do the `if`:

```
let n;
if (n = SomeFunc()) {
    // n is truthy
} else {
    // n is falsy
}
```

If you want to limit the scope of that variable just to that `if`, then put it inside a block:

```
// other code...
{
    let n;
    if (n = SomeFunc()) {
        // n is truthy
    } else {
        // n is falsy
    }
}
// other code...
```

Of course, if your function has no other code, then no extra block is needed: the function's block will apply.

Many will disagree with you that an assignment within an `if` condition is *clean*. Best practice is to avoid such side effects in a condition, although opinions differ on this. Still, it does not take more characters to write it as follows, and it looks cleaner to me:

```
{
    let n = SomeFunc();
    if (n) {
        // n is truthy
    } else {
        // n is falsy
    }
}
```

#### As function expression

One other approach is to use an immediately invoked function expression, to which you provide the function's return value as argument:

```
(n => {
    if (n) {
        // n is truthy
    } else {
        // n is falsy
    }
})(SomeFunc());
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about invoking anonymous functions into this. Thank you for such examples.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

For a terse syntax use ternary operator:

> `var`/`const`/`let` **variable** = (**condition**) `?` **value if true** `:` **value if false**

The parenthesis wrapped around the condition are optional.

---

### Demo

```js
/* 
Condition: if (number is greater than 10) ?
             return true 
           : else return false
*/
const gTTen = number => { return (number > 10) ? true : false; }

console.log(gTTen(11));
console.log(gTTen(9));

function ternary(number) {

  /*
  Using the previous function then store its return in a 
  variable
  */
  const tenFilter = gTTen(number);
  
  /*
  Condition: if (previous value is true AND the number is
             less than 20) ?
               range is 30
               : else range is 0
  */
  let range = (tenFilter && number < 20) ? 30 : 0; 
  
  /*
  Condition: if (range = 30) ? 
               result is (the first string)
               : else result is (the last string)
  */               
  let result = range === 30 ? `${number} is within range` : `${number} is not within range`;
  
  return result;
}

console.log(ternary(50));
console.log(ternary(15));
```

Comment: How would you be able to use the declared variable in the truthy / falsy part of the ternary expression? I believe that is what the OP required when writing *"...and use that further along the statement"*

Comment: @trincot sounds like the OP requires a `switch()` with no `breaks`. It sounds like the OP needs to uncomplicate the real code so as to avoid the need for such tomfoolery.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! I figured this out a few days ago, but didn't have time to respond. I could use local variables that I only overwrite while performing the statements.

Here's an example.

```js
function retClone(bool) {
    return bool; // Returns same input context for example.
}

if (t = retClone(true)) {
    console.log(t); // true
    // t is truthy, because we get `true` returned.
}

if (t = retClone(false)) {
    // Wouldn't run.
    // t is falsy.
} else {
    console.log(t); // false
}
```

Thank you all who responded. ~Q